# After upgrading Node, 'Segmentation fault (core dumped)' error shows up. How can I fix it?

Tags: node.js, npm, segmentation-fault

I was trying to upgrade Node by following the instruction from https://tecadmin.net/upgrade-nodejs-via-npm/. I did `sudo npm cache clean -f`, `sudo npm install -g n`, and `sudo n stable`.
After the above commands, I stupidly did `sudo ln -sf /usr/local/n/versions/node/11.8.0/bin/node /usr/bin/node`. After this command, I checked the `/usr/local/n/versions/node` folder. It had `10.15.3`, so I typed `sudo ln -sf /usr/local/n/versions/node/10.15.3/bin/node /usr/bin/node`.

Right now, `node -v` gives me `10.15.3`. However, `npm -version` gives me `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`. Other commands like `npm update -g` also gives me the same error message.

Other posts about the `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` error don't seem to be directly related to my problem.

How can I fix this?

I am using Ubuntu 19.04.

Thank you.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I faced The same Issue just now,
This because of conflicting the npm of node and nodejs

so remove nodejs by below commands

```
sudo apt-get remove nodejs
```

this will remove all nodejs related Packages,

after above command you have to run autoremove command just like that

```
sudo apt autoremove
```

this will solve the problem,

Now you just have node pacakge in your machine, and NPM (segmentation dumped) error will also resolves.

you can more dig about [What is segmentation fault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2346806/what-is-a-segmentation-fault?rq=1#answer-2346849)

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Comment: it removed all nodejs, npm, node for me. So had to install again

Comment: Not working for me, can you help me a little bit here?

Comment: This works for me when my `npm pack` command failed. However, it does removes all npm related packages installed by `apt-get` but since I manage npm using conda, this isn't an issue for me.

Comment: This must be the funniest error I can encounter in a released version of a famous software... Every execution of npm, with or without any options, yields segfault immediately, and it is resolved after remove all nodejs related packages as described in this answer.

Answer (score 4):

Try to run `npm rebuild` to recompile your dependencies.

Comment: Using pnpm, `pnpm rebuild` worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by "binary incompability" between your compiled binaries and the libraries they are linked against. My list of things that can cause this is:

- Upgrading nodejs, since you need to rebuild the code from clean state
- Docker and shared node_modules, for example if you are sharing on a volume or copying node_modules from Mac to Linux, or from Ubuntu to Alpine Linux. Note that node_modules built for e.g. Mac are not compatible, if shared, with linux (in Docker)
- Docker multistage builds forget the libraries, you had in the earlier stage, unless you explicitly copy them to the next stage
- Vagrant for the same reason as Docker. By chance, it might work, if you have the same Linux distribution running on the same version inside and outside your virtual machine, over which node_modules is shared over a shared folder or a volume, which is more common on Vagrant

Short fix, that works most often, is:

```
rm -rf node_modules
```

Then retry.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [Node Version Manager](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm). Once installed you an easily upgrade downgrade node versions on the fly, with commands like NVM use 16 or NVM use 18.Sometimes I get this segmentation fault error and just quickly switch back to Node 16.

Comment: This problem is due to compatibility in node_modules from before the upgrade.  NVM will not solve this.  Delete and reinstall node_modules with npm.

Answer (score -3):

Try to run the following two commands

```
sudo apt --auto-remove purge npm

sudo apt --auto-remove purge nodejs
```

After executing these commands npm was working without installation.